# How to Convert array element to binary value

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class EncryptionAlgorithm {

   public static void enterText(String plaintext ){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Plaintext: ");
        plaintext = in.nextLine(); 
        int plaintextLenght = plaintext.length();

        int[] array1 = new int[plaintextLenght]; 
        int[] array2 = new int[plaintextLenght]; 

        for(int i = 0; i < plaintextLenght ; i++){  
            char character = plaintext.charAt(i); 
            int ascii = (int) character; 

            array1[i]= ascii / 10; 
            array2[i] = ascii % 10;   

        }
        String temp1 = **Integer.toBinaryString(array1)**;
        String temp2 = **Integer.toBinaryString(array2)**;
        while (temp1.length()!= 8) { 
            temp1 = "0" + temp1;            
        }
        while (temp2.length()!= 8) { 
            temp2 = "0" + temp2;            
        }
        System.out.print("Quotient = "+ Arrays.toString(array1)); 
        System.out.println(" Remainder = "+ Arrays.toString(array2)); 
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str ="";
        enterText(str);

    }
}
```

pls house help me resolve the toBinaryString(), i will be gratful.
thanks

Comment: You have an array of `int`s and you want to make a big binary string by joining together the binary strings of all the individual `int`s, yes?

Comment: Exactly. my challenge is the conversion

Comment: `toBinaryString` takes an `int`, not an array. You'll have to use a loop to apply `toBinaryString` to each `int` individually and append the results into a single output `String`.

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved as following:

**Note:** You can change your `temp1.length()!= 8` condition to `temp1.length() < 8`. Otherwise it will go to infinite loop for a bigger text entered.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EncryptionAlgorithm {

    public static void enterText(String plaintext ){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Plaintext: ");
        plaintext = in.nextLine(); 
        int plaintextLenght = plaintext.length();

        int[] array1 = new int[plaintextLenght]; 
        int[] array2 = new int[plaintextLenght]; 

        for(int i = 0; i < plaintextLenght ; i++){  
            char character = plaintext.charAt(i); 
            int ascii = (int) character; 

            array1[i]= ascii / 10; 
            array2[i] = ascii % 10;   

        }

        List<String> array1Binary = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            array1Binary.add(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
        }

        List<String> array2Binary = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            array2Binary.add(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
        }

        String temp1 = String.join("", array1Binary);
        String temp2 = String.join("", array2Binary);
        while (temp1.length()!= 8) { 
            temp1 = "0" + temp1;            
        }
        while (temp2.length()!= 8) { 
            temp2 = "0" + temp2;            
        }
        System.out.print("Quotient = "+ Arrays.toString(array1)); 
        System.out.println(" Remainder = "+ Arrays.toString(array2)); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = "";
       enterText(str);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Vebbie. would you mind I mail you to guide me through my project work? I will be greatful if you can

Comment: @Onerouyi Stackoverflow is not `help me do my work over email` platform. If the answer solves your problem, you should accept/upvote it and ask another question if you get stuck anywhere else.

Comment: @Onerouyi : I won't mind to help you but SO is here to do the same where you get stuck. You can post your queries and you will find solutions from different perspectives. Thanks.